# Evenly split the columns of a multirow table in lyx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I would like to have a table like this:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[spanish,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10em}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}%
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|C|C|C|}
\hline 
Fkrmula & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\frac{2\alpha}{\beta+5.4\cos{\left(\pi\gamma\right)}}$}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Error & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\sqrt{4\left\lvert {\frac{\Delta_{\alpha}}{\beta+5.4\cos{\left(\pi\gamma\right)}}}\right\rvert ^{2}+4\left\lvert {\frac{\Delta_{\beta}\alpha}{\left(\beta+5.4\cos{\left(\pi\gamma\right)}\right)^{2}}}\right\rvert ^{2}+116.64\pi^{2}\left\lvert {\frac{\Delta_{\gamma}\alpha\sin{\left(\pi\gamma\right)}}{\left(\beta+5.4\cos{\left(\pi\gamma\right)}\right)^{2}}}\right\rvert ^{2}}$ }\tabularnewline
\hline 
Variable & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Valor & $1.02$ & $0.600$ & $5.0$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Error & $0.10$ & $0.006$ & $0.5$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Error en resultado & $2.4$ & $2.3$ & $1.5$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Error total & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$3.7$}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Resultado & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$-15\pm4$}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}

\caption{Errores}
\end{table}

\par\end{center}\selectlanguage{english}%

\end{document}
```

Where the three small columns are evenly split. I have tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49785/how-to-set-equal-size-of-cells-in-tabular-environment-when-multicolumn-extend-t), but columns are only approximately equal when I set the correct parameter of the width. The problem us that I don't know what's going to be inside the cells (as the tables are autogenerated) nor the number of columns, and don't want to manually set the width every time; ie, there can be longer or shorter formulas in the second row and the number of var columns can be different for each table.

Ideally, the resulting table should be editable in the normal lyx gui (not ERT).

Also, I'd like to have more vertical spacing for the formulas.